# How to stop Qt concurrent recursive run function from other thread?

Tags: qt

I want to return from recursive function running in a separate thread from some other thread.

I tried with Recursive mutex , but its not working !!

How can we achieve it ?

```
bool stop = false;
QMutex mutex(QMutex::Recursive);
int count = 1;

void worker_run () {
   QMutexLocker locker(&mutex);
   if(stop)
       return;

    qDebug () << count++;
    worker_run();

}
void worker_stop () {
    QMutexLocker locker(&mutex);
    stop = true;
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QtConcurrent::run(&worker_run);
    QtConcurrent::run(&worker_stop);

    return a.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that the recursive call to worker_run () doesn't unlock the mutex.
Remember that QMutexLocker will unlock when it will go out of scope. Then give it a scope...

```
void worker_run () {
   { QMutexLocker locker(&mutex);
     if(stop)
       return;
   }

   qDebug () << count++;
   worker_run();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove all the mutexes and try again. The reason for that is because worker_run is not a critical region, except for the access to the stop variable, which is granted to be atomic.

I believe you're also missing the volatile qualifier to the stop variable (or at least, use some explicit atomic data type).